# How to make ember component fetch data from server. put AJAX call inside the component seems not a good practise to handle this

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js, ember-data

An Ember Component needs to fetch data from serve, however i think put AJAX call inside the component is not a good practise.

Or use the Route to fetch data, then pass data to component.But the route's method can't share easily between different routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you are right, it is not a good idea to put ajax calls in components. However, in a case where the data to be retrieved and displayed is intimately connected to the view--auto-completion could be one example--it should not be considered an anti-pattern.

If you think it is important to segregate the ajax call, you could consider using a `{{render}}` helper inside the component's template, and do the ajax work in a separate controller with an associated view where the results are displayed. Routes are not really relevant here because they are related to navigation and URLs.

Comment: So make the ajax call inside a controller is not an anti-pattern?

Comment: Not IMHO, if it's "controller-level" data, as opposed to "model" level data.

Comment: `it should not be considered an anti-pattern.` - How do you write an integration test for something like that?

Answer (score 1):

A component should depend only on the input that are passed to it.

If component has some internal dependency (AJAX / Other data) for input it is an anti pattern.

Ember way will be

**1) Create a Route :** (Get data to you application)

Sometime you dont have a route for such data (like in your case). Here you can use application route or any other parent route if have. Use the [setupController](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/) to inject this data to relevant controller

**2) Pass down data to component**

Now your data should be a controller. Pass this data like any other to required component

```
{{my-comp-here data="here" ajaxData=fromRoute }}
```

Comment: In this way, my component is hard to share with other Ember App.Because i need some mixins to make my component work right.

Comment: @ray, No, if you depend only on the data passed through input you won't. Your new ember app has to supply data and component will work fine. Goal is to remove any external dependency apart from input so any application know what component need to work.

Comment: @sushant I agree with you in general, but how would you write a component which did auto-complete based on queries to the serve?